# Run multiple Flask apps on the same domain

Tags: python, apache, flask

I want to run several Flask apps such that...

`mydomain.com` is running one app in one directory.

`mydomain.com/app1` is running another app in another directory.

`mydomain.com/app2` is running a third app in a third directory.

I want to specifically avoid having to have a URL structure like `app1.mydomain.com`

Is this possible under Apache?

Comment: Are your three Flask apps physically separate (i.e. three separate processes), or do you have a single Flask process that exposes these three groups of functionality within a single server? Trying to figure out if you need a reverse proxy in between Apache and your Flask processes.

Comment: They are 3 separate processes.

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590587/multiple-mod-wsgi-apps-on-one-virtual-host-directing-to-wrong-app) help? That is the `mod_wsgi` based solution, without a reverse proxy.

Comment: See: [Application Dispatching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appdispatch/)