# Main and beta WSGI apps

Tags: python, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

OK, so I've been looking around for hours and this has me stumped.

I have an app not yet in production, and my client wants it to split into less stable and more stable. So, I elected to move the dev version into `/var/www/dev` and the semi-stable one copied into `/var/www/master` (until this is debugged, the semi-stable is also at `/var/www` to not break access too badly). The idea is `domain.com` will always be functional, and new stuff / tests will be on `dev.domain.com`.

Therefore, [according the apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html#serverpath), I now have two virtualhosts:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerAdmin email@example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/master"
ServerName domain.com
SSLEngine on
# [ssl stuff]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
WSGIDaemonProcess master_wsgi user=www-data group=www-data
WSGIScriptAlias /master "/var/www/master/src/main.py"
# [ Aliases .... ]
<Directory "/var/www/master/src">
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler wsgi-script .py
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/master">
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler wsgi-script .py
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
 <Location /master>
     # [HTTP auth stuff]
     WSGIProcessGroup master_wsgi
 </Location>
 # modules, cache, error directories, etc
</VirtualHost>
```

Then the exact same thing duplicated, except for :

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/dev"
ServerName dev.domain.com
ServerPath /dev/
```

and all other instances of `master` in aliases, daemon, etc, becoming `dev` (I literally did a `replace-string`). The daemon process and process group were me [chasing another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591232/1877527) that didn't pan out because of the subdirectory requirement (since apparently they both need to be in one VirtualHost, but I can't specify `DocumentRoot` in `<Location>`)

Now, if I do this, all I get is a file list for both. The correct file list, mind, but just file lists.
If I go to either and change the `WSGIScriptAlias` to `/` where the old copy is, it works fine off of that python file as it always has (though of course it means the dev stuff actually points to the old templates, so that's no good since I can't change templates, just scripts, since `templateDir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/../templates/") + "/"` is always `/var/www/templates`).

It's not erroring, it's just giving file lists, so it's pointed at the right place but the WSGIScriptAlias isn't doing what it should? What am I missing?

In case it's relevant, here's the stuff before the relevant VH in the `httpd.conf`, though I doubt it:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGICallableObject app
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/bin/python
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/
## Heading ##</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are separating the instances by VirtualHost, why aren't you wanting to mount the WSGI application at '/' of the site? Why are you having them at different sub URLs?

Anyway, you have a bunch of things you are doing which aren't correct, regardless of that question. Main issues therefore are:

1 - You should never ever set DocumentRoot to be a parent directory of where the source code for your web site is located. PHP may need that, but mod_wsgi doesn't. By having your code under DocumentRoot, you are making it such that if a configuration mistake is made, that people can download your source code. I presume you do not want that, especially if the code contains database passwords and other sensitive information.

2 - The value of WSGIPythonHome is meant to be a directory. Setting it to the location of the Python binary is wrong and setting it in that way wouldn't achieve anything and given that, you likely don't need it.

3 - You don't need both of:

```
<Directory "/var/www/master/src">
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler wsgi-script .py
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/master">
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler wsgi-script .py
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When you specify a Directory/Location block, it applies to sub directories/URLs below that as well.

At the same time, you do not need ExecCGI or the AddHandler directive.

You should in practice only need the Directory block for the directory containing the WSGI script file unless you have static files assets as well.

```
<Directory "/var/www/master/src">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Note of course warning about having things under DocumentRoot.

If you have static file assets, you should use a separate Alias directive to map them in from the directory they reside in with Apache access controls set on that specific directory as necessary. The directory of static assets should not also include your code, so don't mix them, keep them separate.

With things mounted at '/' for each site, a better explanation of the issue you are having with templates would then help.

Comment: Yes, there are static file assets in other aliased directories.

The python path is also a directory (the binary is `python` within that directory).

The reasoning is that ultimately, each subdirectory is essentially a mirror of a git branch (release will have a number of these organizational changes), so they would ideally be wholly self-contained.

Therefore, the templates referred to in `/var/www/master/src` would reference the templates in `/var/www/master/templates`, and the same with `dev`. The idea is to look at `main.py`'s dir, then pick the relative template.

Comment: Though I suppose, now that you mention it, if I keep the app in `/` I could point to one directory if it's asking for a subdomain, and another if it's not .... which should be something like `Request.host_url` in webob with some splitting and checking, but I'd really just as soon have it all self contained for now (see above caveat about release). They're two versions of the same thing, not really two separate apps -- they should just behave like that.

Comment: You pointed me on the right track. A few cleanups and minor fixes later, it started working properly. Thanks!