# How can I have two WSGI Daemon Processes for two Django Apps at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I need to server two Django Apps with Apache and I'm using standard procedure on serving wsgi.py using Apache.

My first Daemon Process is this:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app1 user=www-data group=www-data threads=50 python-home=/usr/bin/python3.6
```

My second Daemon Process is this:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app2 user=www-data group=www-data threads=50 python-home=/usr/bin/python3.6
```

I understood from trial and error that they can't have the same user and group and that If I do what I have done above, one app will function properly and the other will go down.

How could I make this work?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/541020/wsgidaemonprocess-for-each-application-instance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple mod\_wsgi apps on one virtual host directing to wrong app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590587/multiple-mod-wsgi-apps-on-one-virtual-host-directing-to-wrong-app)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of them worked as they suggested solutions on one single Virtualhost, whereas I have two Virtualhosts, one for each App.